# What is the lifecycle of a vertx event bus in a react-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, vert.x

I'm starting from scratch trying to integrate a vertx event bus into a React / Redux application. My first question is what is the lifecyle of the event bus?

Should there be a single instance that is opened when the index page first loads and remains open as the user navigates around the single page app? If so, how do I make the event bus available to each component that might need it? I plan on using service proxies in various React components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using vert.x server side authentication with sessions then you should open the bridge after the login is complete. This ensures the right user is mapped to requests. If your messages are public you can open whenever your component mounts.

Is general the bridge will open a web socket, which is not a big deal, but on flaky connections or old client the bridge will fallback to pooling ajax. This could be an issue for your app (front-end) as its consuming a http connection from your browser pool.

Service proxies do not consume any resources (so to say) they just encode and decode messages over the shared event bus bridge.

Perhaps the logical idea is to bind the event bus to the events, component will mount / unmount so you use the resources only when needed.

Remember that if you do this and the component is not mounted then you can't push from the server as no handler will be listening.

At the end it all depends on what's the problem you're trying to solve.